# bash: echo phrases with the delays on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, echo

As a part of my bash routine I need to print some message in one line according to the following logic

```
echo "Dataset is being rescored !!" | execution of some AWK sctipt | echo "DONE"
```

My realisation:

```
# print pharase 1: initiation of the process
echo -n "Dataset is being rescored.. Please wait"; sleep 0.5 
mkdir ${results}
# Apply the following AWK code
while read -r d; do
awk -F, '
# here is some AWK code that operate with target_file.csv and save output to the $results
}'  "${d}_"*/target_file.csv > "${results}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
# print pharase 2 of the result
echo -n " C"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "O"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "M"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "P"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "L"; echo -n "E"; sleep 0.2; echo -n "T"; echo -n "E"; sleep 0.2; echo "D!"
```

So I assume that phrase 2 is printed after finishing of execution of the AWK script and the both echos don't influence its execution. Is it OK ??

Comment: `echo -n` or `printf`

Comment: could not understand how echo -n could be applied in this way with the definition of the pause between messages. May you post an example ? Thanks +++

Comment: `echo -n "Dataset for is being rescored type fpad"; sleep 1; echo " DONE"`

Comment: This looks like a loading bar that does not actually do something, but just waits to annoy the user. Are you sure `sleep 1` is what you want? I would have waited for the dataset to be rescored.

Comment: yes exactly this is a loaing bar that do nothing :-) If you know another solutions, e.g. to display in the temrinal kind of visualsation of the loading bar, you are welcome here for your answer! Cheers

Comment: The next better thing would be `echo -n Doing thing...; doThing; echo Done`

Comment: OK, I've just done it using echo -n 'Doing thing... '; my_command; echo " Done" it seems that it is the same, right ?

Comment: I've just updated my first message with the real example of what I am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for the waiting animation? There ya go:)

```
#Add some color
. ~/SCR/color

#Animation sprites
sprite=(
    "$YLW($RED* $YLW)  ( $RED*$YLW)"
    "$YLW ($RED* $YLW)( $RED*$YLW) "
    "$YLW ( $RED*$YLW)($RED* $YLW) "
    "$YLW( $RED*$YLW)  ($RED* $YLW)"
    "$YLW($RED* $YLW)  ( $RED*$YLW)")

#get the pid of your process
pid=$(...)

#Waiting animation
i=0; while [ -e /proc/$pid ]; do sleep 0.1
    printf "\r${GRN}Please wait... ${sprite[$i]}$DEF"
    ((i++)); [[ $i = ${#sprite[@]} ]] && i=0
done
```

This animation will be running while the pid of your process exists.

[image: animation]

PS: here is the llink to that [color](https://github.com/vaniacer/bash_color) script